# How to call a class which is in other directory in Python

Tags: python, class

I've a main execution python file (F) where I would like to use some services (S)from other python **class**
the folder structure is :

```
root/a/my file to execute -- (F)
root/b/python class I would like to use -- (S)
```

how can I call to the requested python class (S) within my file (F)?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be too obvious but other answers are missing the need to ensure that module `b` is in your `sys.path`. Thus assuming the folder structure in the question and assuming that directory `b` contains a file called `__init__.py` alongside the module `s.py`, then this incantation is needed:

```
# Add the b directory to your sys.path

import sys, os
parent_dir = os.getcwd() # find the path to module a
# Then go up one level to the common parent directory
path = os.path.dirname(parent_dir)
# Add the parent to sys.pah
sys.path.append(path)

# Now you can import anything from b.s
from b.s import anything
...
```

Comment: gauden - I've followed your instructions, but during the execution (while the code reaches import statement) I'm getting "ImportError" exception - No Module named (name of the folder I've tried to import), as I said,  the sys.path.append did it's job...

Comment: I do get the all files stored in the module I'm trying to import therefore the path I'm creating is ok

Comment: Thanks for the uptick. Shall I assume that your issue was solved? The comment here implies there may still be problems.

Answer (score 1):

Make a example of this question, the following is your current directory tree:

```
A folder:
  file a.py
  file b.py
B folder:
  file c.py
  file d.py
```

In c.py , you want to import a.py to your macro. Then you can do this:

```
import os
# insert 1, 2, 3... but not 0, 0 is your working directory
sys.path.insert(1, "Folder A 's absolute path")
# Here, you can import module A directly    
import a
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `__init__.py` file in the directory you wish to include.

So lets imagine we have two directories, one called `src` the other called `utils`.

If you have `Main.py` inside the `src` directory, and you wish to use a class named `Network` inside a file called `Connections.py` which is located in `utils` Then you could do the following.

Please note, the same applies to any folder you create that has a `*.py` file. For example,we can have `folder a, b, c` and you simply do `from a.b.c import Connections`, or whatever your file name may be...

**1)** Create an `__init__.py` file (it can simply be empty) inside the `utils` directory, then from your `Main.py` do the following.

```
from utils import Connections

my_instance = Connections.Network()

#Then use the instance of that class as so.
my_instance.whateverMethodHere()
```

**The Directory would look like this:**

```
root dir
  - src 
    -__init__.py
    - Main.py

  - utils
    -__init__.py
    - Connections.py
```

For more details, you can check out the python documentation which goes more in-depth.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

**As per the link above, a bit more info on python packages, and why we use `__init__.py`:**

> When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on
>   sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.
>
> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all**
>   variable, described later.

Comment: but how do I include this directory ? I mean what exactly I write after "import..." ?

Comment: and the folder hierarchy, how does it work here ?, I mean if Util is located under root/a/b/c/util